# Vba Button Code error

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am having an error with this code at the Line Else I want it to change the caption if a name has been entered if not then exit

```
Private Sub cmdButton_Click()

    Dim name As String

    With cmdButton

    If .Caption = "CommandButton1" Then

        name = InputBox("Enter Template Name.")

    End If

    If StrPtr(name) = 0& Then Exit Sub

    Else
        .Caption = name

    End If

    End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Len(name) = 0 Then  'exit sub if user doesn't enter a name (or cancels)
 Exit Sub
Else
 .Caption = name
End If
```

Comment: Thank you I will accept the answer in 2 minutes when it lets me.